# List user environment variables batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, variables, cmd, global-variables

How can I list all environment variables for the currently connected user?

I tried `%PATH%` but it returns system variables.

Answer (score 1):

`set` by itself will list all environment variables.

You can also list all environment variables starting with a specific letter by passing that letter to set as a parameter. For example, to see all the variables that start with p, you may use `set p`.

Comment: with `set "` you can list also some "hidden" variables.

Comment: There is no possibility to get only variables for specific user, the "SET" return all environment variables